# Angularjs - jquery error undefined is not a function

Tags: jquery, angularjs

In my angular project when i am trying grunt test, i am getting error as :

```
   PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
      TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'url.indexOf( " " )')
      at /home/rajat/workspace/testProject/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:9612
```

My bower.json :

```
{
  "name": "testProject",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.3.0",
    "bootstrap": "~3.2.0",
    "angular-animate": "~1.3.0",
    "angular-cookies": "~1.3.0",
    "angular-resource": "~1.3.0",
    "angular-route": "~1.3.0",
    "angular-sanitize": "~1.3.0",
    "angular-touch": "~1.3.0",
    "angular-ui": "~0.4.0",
    "toastr": "~2.1.2",
    "jquery.cookie": "jquery-cookie#~1.4.1",
    "angular-material": "~0.11.4",
    "angular-bootstrap": "~0.14.2",
    "angular-slick": "^0.2.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.6.3",
    "angular-backtop": "*",
    "ngInfiniteScroll": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-rangeslider": "^0.0.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "~1.3.0"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "~1.3.0"
  },
  "appPath": "app",
  "moduleName": "testProject",
  "overrides": {
    "bootstrap": {
      "main": [
        "less/bootstrap.less",
        "dist/css/bootstrap.css",
        "dist/js/bootstrap.js"
      ]
    },
    "angular-ui": {
      "main": [
        "build/angular-ui.js"
      ]
    },
    "angular-bootstrap": {
      "main": [
        "ui-bootstrap.min.js",
        "ui-bootstrap-csp.css",
        "ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

And my package.json :

```
{
  "name": "testProject",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.5",
    "grunt-angular-templates": "~0.5.7",
    "grunt-autoprefixer": "~2.0.0",
    "grunt-concurrent": "~1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "~0.9.0",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.12.0",
    "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "~0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "~0.9.2",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.11.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.6.1",
    "grunt-filerev": "~2.1.2",
    "grunt-google-cdn": "~0.4.3",
    "grunt-karma": "*",
    "grunt-newer": "~1.1.0",
    "grunt-ng-annotate": "~0.9.2",
    "grunt-svgmin": "~2.0.0",
    "grunt-usemin": "~3.0.0",
    "grunt-wiredep": "~2.0.0",
    "grunt-velocity": "~0.1.0",
    "jit-grunt": "~0.9.1",
    "jshint-stylish": "~1.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "*",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "*",
    "time-grunt": "~1.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "~0.13.15",
    "phantomjs": "~1.9.19"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "grunt test"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "grunt-ng-constant": "~1.1.0"
  }
}
```

I am not able to resolve this issue as when i run project debugger also gives error as Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: check your code for an error where it says `url.indexOf( " " )`

Comment: its in bower components. can't change the code inside that